# Count number of rows with a column within another column

Tags: mysql

Data:

```
col1 | col2
-----------
asd | bbbb
as | asss
abb | babb
```

col1 of row 2 and 3 appear in col2 so the answer should be 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM col t
WHERE t.col2 LIKE concat( '%', t.col1, '%' )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `like`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.col2 like concat('%', t.col1, '%');
```